Couldn't authenticate with keytab while discovering which salt to use: KDC has no support for encryption type
I try to join a RHEL 8 machine to the domain of a Windows Server 2019 domain controller using realmd. The join kind of works, a computer account gets created in active directory, but I am not able to login to the RHEL machine using an AD account.
During domain join, there is a non-terminating error (it does not abort realmd):
realmd[...]: ! Couldn't authenticate with keytab while discovering which salt to use: MYCOMPUTER$@MY.DOMAIN.TLD: KDC has no support for encryption type

During runtime, the following error is logged repeatedly (recurring):
ldap_child[...]: Failed to initialize credentials using keytab [MEMORY:/etc/krb5.keytab]: KDC has no support for encryption type. Unable to create GSSAPI-encrypted LDAP connection.

Both errors suggest, that there are no matching encryption types for Kerberos ("KDC has no support for encryption type"). I am familiar with this problem and can confirm that there are matching encryption types, namely:



Windows
RHEL




RC4_HMAC_MD5



AES128_CTS_HMAC_SHA1_96
AES128_CTS_HMAC_SHA1_96


AES256_CTS_HMAC_SHA1_96
AES256_CTS_HMAC_SHA1_96



Why does the error "KDC has no support for encryption type" pop up, if there are actually two matching encryption types?

It turned out, that there is a Kerberos bug in the "latest" Windows Server 2019 ISO image (namely November 2022). There is a hotfix for that, but that hotfix will not be installed automatically through Windows Update or WSUS. You have to do it manually.
After installing that hotfix, RHEL 8 can be joined to the domain successfully. Further reading:

November 2022 Out of Band update released! Take action!
KB5021131: How to manage the Kerberos protocol changes related to CVE-2022-37966
17. November 2022 – KB5021655 (BS-Build 17763.3653) Out-of-Band
Network security: Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos


That OOB hotfix has been very likely included in a later cumulative update. On which update level is this system?

It is an IaC environment where I tear up and down whole AD environments regularly. The DC was on the level of the "latest" ISO image.

Windows updates/fixes are cumulative and are incorporated into the cumulative update the following month. The KB5021655 OOB update was superseded by the December 2022 monthly update, it says it right on Microsoft Catalog. https://imgur.com/a/ruRnusr

If the issue were not fixed in the latest monthly update, that would mean there has been what is known as a regression. That would be an issue to report.

@stackprotector the latest ISO image is, as you say, from 2022. When you deploy a system from it, you absolutely need to run a full Windows Update.
